# Process problems when running Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I want to execute Laravel jobs through a queue but I can't find the good way to launch the queue and to call a method when the queue is empty.

My controller generates menus (word files) for my customers, after their creations I'd like to download all the files under one zip folder.

**So the process is the following :**

1- The user click on a button in the front end to create my customers' menus

2- Jobs are dispatched to a queue (to generate all the menus of the day)

3- Queue is started

4- When the queue is empty, directly download the files to the user's browser

**To sum up everything**, I have a problem of sync between all my processes. I don't know how to start the queue and how to call the method that will download the newly generated files.

Here is what I've done so far :

From my controller :

```
    public function menusEdition(Request $request){

    $date = $request->date;
    $day = DB::table('days')->where('calendarDate','=',$date)->pluck('day')[0];

    $menus = Menu::where('day',$day)->get();

    foreach($menus as $menu){
        $job = new MenusEdition($menu);
        $this->dispatch($job);
    }

    Artisan::call('queue:work --stop-when-empty');

    $this->downloadDayMenus($date);     //Method that downloads all the menus of the day

    return back();
}

public function downloadDayMenus($date){
    $folderPath = storage_path('app\public\archived-menus\\'.$date);

    $rootPath = realpath($folderPath);

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zipName = $rootPath.'/'.$date.'-menus.zip';
    $zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // Create recursive directory iterator
    /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
        if (!$file->isDir())
        {
            // Get real and relative path for current file
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

            // Add current file to archive
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }

    // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
    $zip->close();

    return response()->download($zipName);
}
```

From my job "MenuEdition" :

```
class MenusEdition implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  protected $menu;

  /**
   * Create a new job instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct($menu)
  {
      $this->menu = $menu;
  }

  /**
   * Execute the job.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function handle(MenusController $menusController)
  {
      $menu = $this->menu;
      $menuFile = $menusController->templateEdition($menu->id);
      return;
  }

}
```

Remark : For some reason, after making the call to the artisan command, the user is redirected to a blank page...

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

A queue is asynchronous, meaning it is processed in the background rather than during the request. This means the user is not able to interact with the result of the queue directly. However you could think of alternatives like

- Mail the menus to the user once the queue is finished processing
- Add a button to your UI which gets enabled once the queue is finished processing

If you would like the menus to be processed synchronous then you should not be using a queue.

Comment: Ok, good suggestions !
By any chance do you know why I get a blank page after calling the function    Artisan::call('queue:work --stop-when-empty'); ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I do not know why this happens. But I would recommend against running the `queue:work` command from a controller. It should be run via the commandline, usually using [supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration)